# How to assign multiple enum values to a property in Spring.NET configuration?

Tags: c#, spring.net

.NET supports the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx%20FlagsAttribute) for enum's, which indicates "that an enumeration can be treated as a bit field".

An example of an enum that makes use of this [Flags] attribute is [System.Windows.Forms.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx)

Here is my Spring.NET object definition:

```xml
<object id="command.paste" type="MyNamespace.PasteClipboardCommand, MyProject">
  <property name="Title" value="Paste into Folder" />
  <property name="ShortcutKeys" value="P" />
</object>
```

This sets the property ShortcutKeys of type Keys to the key P. No problem there. However, since this is a shortcut, I'd like to assign something like Control+P as shortcut key.

If I would wire this up in code, it would be:

```
command.ShortcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.P;
```

So, maybe I was a little naive trying this:

```xml
<property name="ShortcutKeys" value="Control|P" />
```

This fails, because the EnumConverter can only parse/convert string representations of single enum's. A full stacktrace is available below.

- Is this possible by default Spring.NET ?
- Can I work around this by specifying/using another EnumConverter ?
- Should I create/use another Keys class to do the Spring.NET initialization ?

**UPDATE:**

Apparently the KeysConverter knows how to handle this like this:

```
(new KeysConverter()).ConvertFrom(null, null, "Control+P");
```

Unfortunately, the EnumConverter does not support this ?

**Attached Stacktrace:**

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested PropertyAccessExceptions are: 
[Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException: Cannot convert property value of type [System.String] to required type [System.Windows.Forms.Keys] for property 'ShortcutKeys'., Inner Exception: System.FormatException: Control|P is not a valid value for Keys. ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Control|P' was not found.
    at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
    at System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
    at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(String text)
    at Spring.Core.TypeConversion.TypeConversionUtils.ConvertValueIfNecessary(Type requiredType, Object newValue, String propertyName)] ---> Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException: Error creating object with name 'command.builder.paste' defined in 'file [....\commands.xml] line 39' : Error setting property values: PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested PropertyAccessExceptions are: 
[Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException: Cannot convert property value of type [System.String] to required type [System.Windows.Forms.Keys] for property 'ShortcutKeys'., Inner Exception: System.FormatException: Control|P is not a valid value for Keys. ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Control|P' was not found.
    at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
    at System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
    at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(String text)
    at Spring.Core.TypeConversion.TypeConversionUtils.ConvertValueIfNecessary(Type requiredType, Object newValue, String propertyName)] ---> PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested PropertyAccessExceptions are: 
[Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException: Cannot convert property value of type [System.String] to required type [System.Windows.Forms.Keys] for property 'ShortcutKeys'., Inner Exception: System.FormatException: Control|P is not a valid value for Keys. ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'Control|P' was not found.
    at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
    at System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
    at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(String text)
    at Spring.Core.TypeConversion.TypeConversionUtils.ConvertValueIfNecessary(Type requiredType, Object newValue, String propertyName)]
```

Comment: Not a solution but a workaround is to store the underlying numeric value, not the enum itself.

Comment: Nice find - you can post an answer to your own question and accept it, but only after a day. Please do this later on, so we can all see your problem was solved and upvote your answer too ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I will post it tomorrow. I actually found the '+' feature for the KeysConverter by looking at the mono source code.

Comment: Posted my own answer below now :-)

Comment: I'll give @bbaia a bit more time to provide some more information to address the issues with his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the Spring.NET documentation [5.11 Configuration of IApplicationContext](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#context-configuration), you can see an example of how to add a specific type converter for a given type.

Adding the KeysConverter for type Keys in app.config is sufficient:

```
<converter for="System.Windows.Forms.Keys, System.Windows.Forms" type="System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter, System.Windows.Forms"/>
```

Now the enumvalue/shortcut can be specified like this:

```
<property name="ShortcutKeys" value="Control+P" />
```

Comment: Nice! Did not think about this one !

Answer (score 1):

Try using SpEL (Spring.NET Expression Language) :
http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html

```xml
<property name="ShortcutKeys" expression="Keys.Control or Keys.P" />
```

or

```xml
<property name="ShortcutKeys" expression="T(System.Windows.Forms.Keys).Control or T(System.Windows.Forms.Keys).P" />
```

Comment: The first option fails with: Initialization of object failed : Cannot initialize property or field node 'Keys' because the specified context is null. ---> Spring.Core.NullValueInNestedPathException: Cannot initialize property or field node 'Keys' because the specified context is null.

Comment: The second option fails with: Initialization of object failed : Could not load type from string value 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control'. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type from string value 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control'.

Comment: The first option fails, because the Keys enum isn't in mscorlib, you have to register it with the Spring TypeRegistry, see the [docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-typeregistration).

Comment: I've edited the answer; the second option no longer fails in my test.

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<property name="ShortcutKeys" value="Control, P" />
```